# What does this condition for linear independence mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

Learning about linear regression, the following statement was made in the course notes:

> $Xd=0$ only if $d=0$  $\Leftrightarrow $ columus of $X$ are linearly
> indepentent

Here is $X$ a (n x k) matrix and $d$ is a (kx1) vector

**Question**

The above is considered prerequisite knowlegde for the course, but unfortunately I am not familliar with this statement.

Why is the quoted statement true?

Comment: What do you already know about linear independence and matrix multiplication? The shortest answer is "because $Xd$ is a linear combination of the columns of $X$", but depending on what you do know, you may or may not need more information than that.

Comment: The LHS says that $\ker(X)=0$. So the columns cannot be linearly dependent.

Comment: The statement is slightly ambiguous, so here's a better version: $$(\forall d,(Xd=0\iff d=0))\iff(\text{columns of }X\text{ are linearly independent})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide you some information about your problem;

Let $X = (a_{ij})$ with $i = 1,\dots,n$ and $j = 1,\dots,k$ be our matrix and $d = (d_1,\dots,d_k)$ be the vector. Now, \begin{equation}Xd = \begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^ka_{1i}d_i\\
\sum_{i=1}^ka_{2i}d_i\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^ka_{ni}d_i\end{pmatrix},\end{equation}and being linear independent means that any linear combination of the columns that yields zero must have all scalars equal to zero.

Regarding the $\Rightarrow$ direction: We want to prove the columns are linear independent, this means that for each $i = 1,2,\dots,n$ and any scalar sequence $(\alpha_i)_{i =1}^k \subset \mathbb{K}$ we have $$\sum_{j=1}^k\alpha_ja_{ij} = \alpha_1a_{i1} + \alpha_2a_{i2} + \dots + \alpha_na_{ik} = 0,$$imply that $(\alpha_i) = 0$. Indeed, this is exactly given by your hypothesis. Notice that the sums correspond with the ones in $Xd$ above, and we know that $Xd = 0$ imply that $d = 0$ which means that our linear combination of each column with a scalar sequence $(\alpha_i)_1^k$ is zero if the sequence itself is null.

For the opposite direction I will leave it to you.

Good luck!